# CREATE SUPER USER in PaaS offering of Azure Database for Postgres?

Tags: postgresql-11, azure-postgresql

i logged into the azure Postgres database , with the admin user credentials , that i gave at the time of creating the Azure Database for Postgres

Now when i try to create SUPERUSER , by giving the command
CREATE USER TESTER SUPERUSER; ---> it gives me error saying
**must be superuser to create superusers**

I was thinking , the ADMIN USER that i created for Azure Database for Postgres is itself the SUPER USER. Can we not create SUPER USERS in Azure Database for PostgreSQL

Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer myself.

In Azure Postgres , we cannot CREATE SUPERUSERS .
Since this service is a managed PaaS service, only Microsoft is part of the super user role.
Details in link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/howto-create-users)